# manifest.json not found in source code in local directory of many firefox webextensions

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, fedora-25, manifest.json, web-extensibility

I am inspecting source code of Firefox web extensions by looking into *.xpi files located in Mozzila directory.

In my local computer, which runs Fedora 25 - Firefox 52, it is

`~/.mozilla/firefox/415m46wm.default/extensions`

The current issue I am encountering is that when I extract *.xpi file, none of them has the `manifest.json` file. As a result, using `web-ext` to test add-on locally is not possible. [Find out more about web-ext here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different types of Firefox extensions. The most likely reason you are not seeing a *manifest.json* is that the specific add-ons which you are looking at are not WebExtensions. Basically, if it was a WebExtension, it would have a *manifest.json*. The fact that it does not have a *manifest.json*, means it is not a WebExtension. WebExtensions have only existed for a relatively short period of time. The significant majority of extensions will be of other types. The [Introduction to Firefox add-ons](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324) provides some brief information on the files used in the different types which may help you identify the type of add-on you are looking at.

Without you providing the code for the add-on in the question, a pointer to the extension on AMO, or, *at a minimum*, a list of the files contained in the extension's root directory (which may, or may not be enough), there is no way for us to say what type of add-on you are looking at.

Using `web-ext` is not possible on other types of add-ons. If the add-on is restartless (i.e. does not require you to restart Firefox in order to install or uninstall it), you should be able to [load it as a temporary add-on](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910022241/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/26613/installing-a-temporary-add-on#t=20170910022241247808) from `about:debugging`.

Comment: Excellent and informative answer. It is true that I am new to Firefox WebExtensions so I am unaware of the fact of its very recent existence. The description of Stackoverflow document is straightforward and clear enough to identify the add-on type, and furthermore I am inspecting many extensions simultaneously. So I am not going to upload the code : p